# Display Systemd's ExecStart instruction with resolved environment variables

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

Wondering if there's a way to extract the complete `ExecStart` instruction utilized by any given systemd service. See that by "complete" I'm referring to the interpreted version of the `ExecStart` string, not the literal one displayed when you do something like:

```
systemctl show kubelet.service -p ExecStart
```

Example:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf

[Service]
...
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/opt/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

The typical `systemctl show <svc>` instruction shows the 'literal' string ...

```
$ systemctl show kubelet.service -p ExecStart --no-pager | cut -d";" -f2 | sed 's@argv\[\]=@@' | sed 's@^ @@'
/opt/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

But I'm looking for the interpreted version of the above so that the content of the environment variables is properly displayed.

I would expect this state to be available somewhere in systemd's engine, as I believe that this one must be already aware of the existence of the environment-files where these variables are expected (as declared above in `EnvironmentFile` clause).

And sure, I can write a script to parse the service file and obtain all this info, but I suspect / hope that there's an easier approach.

Comment: Related QA over at ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/q/803844

Comment: Thanks @Haxiel, that link was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can query `/proc` to see the process' environment.

```
# MainPID=$(systemctl show -p MainPID docker.service | cut -d '=' -f 2)
# cat "/proc/$MainPID/environ" | tr '\0' '\n'
LANG=C.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
NOTIFY_SOCKET=/run/systemd/notify
LISTEN_PID=1230
LISTEN_FDS=1
LISTEN_FDNAMES=docker.socket
INVOCATION_ID=4f91e56391f742b2aefa4252b6760f42
JOURNAL_STREAM=9:36808
```

Comment: Good idea @henry-menke. It's definitely a fair approximation, but I was hoping to find a systemd-based approach that would save me the need to identify the "overlaps" among the different env-vars being utilized. And by that I mean: given these two vars declared within a systemd unit: ENV_VAR_1="--admin-state=true" and ENV_VAR_2="--admin-state=false", how do you know which one will prevail (last one) without having to parse the systemd file?